# shopware 6 cart line items duplicate results

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

giving the the below code example

```
private function test(Cart $cart): LineItemCollection
{
    return $cart->getLineItems()->filter(function (LineItem $item) {
        // Only consider products, not custom line items or promotional line items
        if ($item->getType() !== LineItem::PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE) {
            return false;
        }
        $exampleInLabel = $item->getLabel();
```

and one item is in the cart, the exampleInLabel is the label twice.

this is is the same with any other function, like `getPayloadValue()` or `getQuantity()` and so on.

how to overcome this?

Comment: Is this method called in a  `CartProcessor`? or where is it called? Keep in mind that the processors may run multiple times during the calculation, so it may happen that the code in question is simply executed in twice, because shopware reruns the cart calculation.

Comment: @j_elfering yes its the in `CartProcessor` and i understand that shopware goes over the cart multiple time to "enrich" the data based on the rules. However, my issue still exists...if i need to get the quantity of an item for creating further rules, i would get 33 for example instead of just 3...and so on...any solution?

Answer (score 0):

try perfroming this in subscriber maybe in beforeLineItemAddedEvent

Answer (score 0):

If the only way to process your code is to put in the CartProcessor which is executed multiple times, you can set a runtime class property which is set to false, and then is set to true when processed first time. Before adding your quantity you check if this property is false.

```php
private bool $hasBeenProcessedAlready = false;

private function test(Cart $cart): LineItemCollection
{
    return $cart->getLineItems()->filter(function (LineItem $item) {
        // Only consider products, not custom line items or promotional line items
        if (
            $item->getType() !== LineItem::PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE
            || $hasBeenProcessedAlready
        ) {
            return false;
        }
        $exampleInLabel = $item->getLabel();
        $this->hasBeenProcessedAlready = true;
```

might not be the prettiest way, but should solve your problem.